# Passing attached File in JSON format

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to pass attached file from HTML5 to Back end via JSON format.

HTML:-

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="idattach" onchange="onattachclick();" accept="text/*">
```

JavaScript:- we have to read above file and convert into base64 format and send through JSON format. Please fill the below ????

```
var filecont = document.getElementById("idattach").files[0];
if (filecont) {                 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(filecont);
    ???????
}
base64.encode(???????);
```

Thanks,
Prasad.

Comment: var imageData = $scope.image1.compressed.dataURL.toString();
var byteCharacters = atob(imageData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|jpg);base64,/, ''));
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}

var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var blob = new Blob([ byteArray ], {
   type : undefined
});

Comment: try this approach may be it work

Comment: I have used above code to encode image in angular js

Comment: Thanks for your response. my question is, how to read attached file before encoding and passing through JSON.